# Как запретить добавлять в БД любые файлы, кроме .csv формата? Python Django Rest Api

Tags: python, django

У меня есть бд:
[image: БД]

Не понимаю, как разрешить добавлять в бд только .csv формат файлы.

```
#models.py
class CSV_BD(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

#serializers.py
class CSVSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CSV_BD
        fields = ('title', 'file')

class CSVViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CSV_BD.objects.all().order_by('title')
    serializer_class = CSVSerializer
```

Comment: Покажите код в контроллере, где вы сохраняете экземпляр модели

Comment: @Mattern надеюсь, добавил то, что вы имели ввиду.

Comment: Нет, код, где вы прнимаете запрос и сохраняете данные из него

Comment: Я  добавлял файлы через кнопку POST на запущенном сервере. (Там автоматически интерфейс от Rest Api идет).

Comment: @Mattern
Предлагаете в views.py добавить страницу, где будут "кнопочки", куда можно вписать название файла и выложить сам файл, а после того, как пользователь нажмёт кнопку "отправить", посмотреть, является ли файл .csv таблицей?

Comment: Ну, +- это и хотел предложить, да

Comment: @Mattern, я об этом догадался после вашего сообщения. Ибо в тестовом задании сказано: "Требования к фронтенду не предъявляются, интерфейс взаимодействия — RestFull API;". Поэтому зациклился исключительно на этой стандартной страничке. Cпасибо!!